# Is there a way to get the input Transcript from LEX into a lambda which then allows connect to grab that transcript and set it as a contact attribute?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I have this lambda below that gets items from DynamoDB and returns it to connect just fine... however, I cannot seem to get the inputTranscript over. Is there a way I could implement this in my current lambda so that Connect can access it? I am seriously stumped on this, as everything I have tried in the documentation has not worked for me.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  console.log(`DEBUG:\t Event`, JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));

  var params = {
    Key: {
      "name": {
        "S": '"' + event.slots.list + '"'
      }
    },
    TableName: 'ServiceOfferings'
  };

  dynamodb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) { 
        console.log("ERROR:\t", err);
        callback(err);
    } else { 
        console.log(data);
        if (data.Item) {
          console.log('data returned from DynamoDB ', JSON.stringify(data));
          callback(null, {
            ServiceOffering: data.Item.name.S.slice(1, -1)
          });
        }
        else {
          console.log("no callback number found for intent");
          callback(new Error("no callback number found for intent"));
        }
    }
  });
};
```

The test instance I use to ensure the lambda works correctly is as follows:

```
{
  "dialog-state": "ReadyForFulfillment",
  "input-transcript": "my printer is not working",
  "slots": {
    "list": "Re-IP Project - Printers"
  },
  "intent-name": "getServiceOffering"
}
```

The response after Testing this comes out to:

```
{
  "ServiceOffering": "Re-IP Project - Printers"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you log the event, you should be able to see the `inputTranscript` being passed to your Lambda. So you simply need to take it out of the event and do with it what you want.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  console.log(`DEBUG:\t Event`, JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));
  var inputTranscript = event.inputTranscript

     ...

      callback(null, {
        ServiceOffering: data.Item.name.S.slice(1, -1),
        inputTranscript: inputTranscript   
      });
```

That includes the inputTranscript in your callback to Connect (I assume), and you can use the Set Attribute block to save and handle the input within Connect.